How to properly write a server-side game loop?
I'm writing a game server in C# and I need to have a loop that invokes Update method 60 times per second.
I tried to make it myself and wrote this:
async Task TickLoop() {
    const int tps = 60;
    const int maxTPS = 3;

    Logger.Information("HPET enabled: {Value}", Stopwatch.IsHighResolution);

    TimeSpan targetDeltaTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d / tps);
    TimeSpan maximumDeltaTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1d / maxTPS);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    TimeSpan lastTick = stopwatch.Elapsed;

    while (true) {
        TimeSpan currentTick = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        TimeSpan deltaTime = TimeSpanUtils.Min(currentTick - lastTick, maximumDeltaTime);

        lastTick = currentTick;

        try {
            Logger.Information($"Delta time: {deltaTime}; TPS: {1 / deltaTime.TotalSeconds}");

            // todo
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.Error(e, "Caught an exception in game loop");
        }

        TimeSpan freeTime = targetDeltaTime - (stopwatch.Elapsed - currentTick);

        if (freeTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
            await Task.Delay(freeTime);
    }
}

Howewer, according to the logs, it invokes 62 times per second:
Delta time: 00:00:00.0159905; TPS: 62,53713142178168
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160048; TPS: 62,48125562331301
Delta time: 00:00:00.0162349; TPS: 61,595698156440754
Delta time: 00:00:00.0157741; TPS: 63,395058989102395
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160049; TPS: 62,48086523502178
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160575; TPS: 62,27619492449012
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169454; TPS: 59,013065492700086
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160029; TPS: 62,48867392785058
Delta time: 00:00:00.0165768; TPS: 60,3252738767434
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160028; TPS: 62,4890644137276
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160041; TPS: 62,48398847795252
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169812; TPS: 58,88865333427556
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160020; TPS: 62,49218847644045
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160004; TPS: 62,49843753906152
Delta time: 00:00:00.0162851; TPS: 61,40582495655538
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169158; TPS: 59,11632911242743
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160949; TPS: 62,13148264357033
Delta time: 00:00:00.0159907; TPS: 62,53634925300331
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169858; TPS: 58,87270543630562
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160045; TPS: 62,482426817457586
Delta time: 00:00:00.0162416; TPS: 61,57028864151316
Delta time: 00:00:00.0160519; TPS: 62,29792111837228
Delta time: 00:00:00.0159664; TPS: 62,63152620503057

I tried replacing Task.Delay with Thread.Sleep and that "solved" the problem:
Delta time: 00:00:00.0168171; TPS: 59,46328439505027
Delta time: 00:00:00.0163640; TPS: 61,10975311659741
Delta time: 00:00:00.0167748; TPS: 59,613229367861315
Delta time: 00:00:00.0172399; TPS: 58,00497682701176
Delta time: 00:00:00.0168041; TPS: 59,509286424146495
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169840; TPS: 58,87894488930759
Delta time: 00:00:00.0168015; TPS: 59,51849537243698
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170069; TPS: 58,79966366592384
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170132; TPS: 58,77789010885665
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169979; TPS: 58,83079674548033
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169138; TPS: 59,1233194196455
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169892; TPS: 58,860923410166464
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170012; TPS: 58,819377455709
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170006; TPS: 58,821453360469626
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170160; TPS: 58,76821814762577
Delta time: 00:00:00.0172717; TPS: 57,89818026019442
Delta time: 00:00:00.0161239; TPS: 62,01973467957504
Delta time: 00:00:00.0169921; TPS: 58,850877760841804
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170062; TPS: 58,802083945855045
Delta time: 00:00:00.0171900; TPS: 58,17335660267597
Delta time: 00:00:00.0168114; TPS: 59,483445757045814
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170135; TPS: 58,77685367502277
Delta time: 00:00:00.0170050; TPS: 58,80623346074684

But, as you can see, sometimes (and quite often) there are moments when TPS becomes above 60, but at other times it stays at 58, which is not very nice to see either.
I know I can just do that:
TimeSpan deltaTime = TimeSpanUtils.Clamp(currentTick - lastTick, targetDeltaTime, maximumDeltaTime);

, but would the code work correctly in that case?
And in general, is it possible that I don't understand something and everything should be like this?

If you're averaging 60 fps, then what is the problem?  All "delay" APIs are only approximate.  It's only guaranteed you'll wait AT LEAST as long as you asked.  When a timer expires, all that does is make your thread "ready to run".  It won't actually run until the scheduler fires up again to do its periodic tasks.

Also, if you have the clients send information about user input that will not be in sync with your heartbeat.  At tick 20 you might get a message for a player doing something at tick 11.  Something to plan for.

Both your images consist entirely of text.  You should post the text in text format (with preformatted markdown if you wish.)  Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Maybe consider PeriodicTimer.

Thank you all for the answers, I will continue to use Task.Delay.

I worked on a similar project, but it was Minecraft Custom Server Software, the problem with both Thread.Sleep() and Task.Delay is that they are not accurate when it comes to waiting in millisecond units, see here:
Stopwatch sw = new();
while (true)
{
   sw.Restart();
   await Task.Delay(3);
   Console.WriteLine("Awaited: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

Output:
Awaited: 16
Awaited: 18
Awaited: 17
Awaited: 8
Awaited: 14
Awaited: 18
Awaited: 11
Awaited: 14
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 15
Awaited: 19
Awaited: 11

As can be seen, this is a total, imprecise wait for units of milliseconds. But this behavior is expected, when you call Thread.Sleep or Task.Sleep, you give the system the possibility to use this thread briefly, therefore it is an imprecise wait, use Thread.Sleep/Task.Delay when millisecond accuracy is not expected.
During my research I came across PeriodicTimer, its accuracy is very high and the problem is that it is a period, that means if the tick extends beyond the limit then the next one is more stealthy, but overall it works quite well but it is not a complete solution.
This means that if Thread.Sleep/Task.Delay is not accurate and PerioditTimer is not what we want, then the only thing we can do at this point is to use our own implementation. My recommendation is this.
If the remaining tick time in milliseconds is:

Less than 5ms Do nothing just continue to next tick.
Less than 15ms Busy wait (empty loop), then continue to next tick.
More than 15ms Call Thread.Sleep/Task.Delay.

Busy wait is negligible if it is performed in a very short time (less than 20ms).
